# how to override rpm macro

Tags: fedora, rpm

I have spent around  3 hrs now.  How to override a macro during rpm build ?
I want to override _sbindir (/usr/sbin) to /opt/sbin I have edited rpm macro files both system and local user files nothing seems to be working for me.
I'm using Fedora 12.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try and override _foo macros. But if you really must, add this to the top of your specfile.

```
%define _sbindir /foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining it from the `rpmbuild` command-line? The `--showrc` switch shows you the "level" at which various macros are defined. There is a hierarchy in case something is defined in more than one place, where -8 (command-line) wins out over -14 (disk, i.e. ~/.rpmmacros file).

```
$ rpmbuild --showrc | grep ' _sbindir'

-14: _sbindir       %{_exec_prefix}/sbin
%global _sbindir    %{_exec_prefix}/sbin

$ rpmbuild --define "_sbindir /tmp/wtf" --showrc | grep ' _sbindir'

-8: _sbindir        wtf
%global _sbindir    %{_exec_prefix}/sbin
```

FWIW, on my CentOS-6 host, the `%global` is defined in the /etc/rpm/macros.scl file.

Comment: I have RPM version 4.0.4 and it doesn't show the line with "wtf" (Output doesn't change at all)